# Remove an element from JSON and convert it to JSON array in Logic Apps

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I’m parsing HTTP response in Logic Apps and getting the following JSON

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "@xmlns": "http://www.something.com",
    "@xmlns:i": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "definition": [
      {
        "id": "11111111",
        "name": "11111111",
        "URL": "11111111"
      },
      {
        "id": "11111112",
        "name": "11111112",
        "URL": "11111112"
      },
      {
        "id": "11111113",
        "name": "11111113",
        "URL": "11111113"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Would like to remove first 4 lines and convert to JSON array.

The result I am looking to achieve:

```
[
      {
        "id": "11111111",
        "name": "11111111",
        "URL": "11111111"
      },
      {
        "id": "11111112",
        "name": "11111112",
        "URL": "11111112"
      },
      {
        "id": "11111113",
        "name": "11111113",
        "URL": "11111113"
      }
    ]
```

Please share your thoughts.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Compose** Connector to get a Required values in JSON.

In a **Compose** Connector add a Input values which you want to get from JSON.

```
"inputs": {
"triggerBody()?[‘Use json object which you want to use’]”
}
```

Here, You are looking for **definition** JSON object. You can use **definition object** in a *Compose* Connector to get a required value.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Use "Parse JSON" connector to get that key-value pair in the logic app during run time. Choose "Use sample payload to generate the schema" to get the schema, by pasting the payload you have in the question.
   [image]
2. This would allow you to choose the exact element that you want, "definition" in your case from the dynamic expression dropdown
   [image]